# Override command for make from outside

Tags: bash, makefile, overriding, cat, unix-ar

I have several dirs with files stamp1.txt and stamp0.txt, and i want override cat command. I need it for example to suppress 'stamp1' files from archiving into library.

So i wrote little filter program called 'realname' and bash script to override original cat command.

```
function cat() { 

    local e=""

    for s in $@
    do
        if realname $s; then
            e=$e" "$s;
        fi
    done

    command cat $e;
}
```

So command:

```
cat dir1/stamp1.txt dir2/stamp0.txt
```

will be converted to

```
cat dir2/stamp0.txt
```

And this example works just fine

```
ar cruv some_lib.a `cat dir1/stamp1.txt dir2/stamp0.txt`
```

But when i run some makefile to build some software - inside this process used original cat nor overrided.

**How to override cat or any other command in way to get it work for make process without changing makefile**(makefile is 3rdparty software and i don't want patch it every time when upgrade is needed)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to move or rename `stamp1.txt`?

Comment: In my view, step (1) make sure to use a macro `CAT = cat` and reference it in the command line (so `ar cruv some_lib.a `cat dir1/stamp1.txt dir2/stamp0.txt` becomes ```${AR} ${ARFLAGS} ${LIBNAME} `${CAT} ${STAMP1} ${STAMP2}` ```) and (2) adjust either `STAMP1=` or `CAT=your-shell-script` (script, not function!) on the Make command line.  If everything is a macro, you can tweak the result as you want – within very broad limits.  If you hard-wire command names or option flags, you lose some of the flexibility.  Using macros extensively is a good idea, regardless of the immediate problem.

Comment: Other people's makefiles present problems — they aren't always written with maximal macros.  If they ignore that advice (they probably do), then consider the merits of `sed 's/cat dir1/mycat dir1/' makefile > makefile.new; make -f makefile.new; rm -f makefile.new` where you edit the makefile on the fly.  You may need a more sensitive search condition than what I outlined in the `sed` command.

Answer (score 1):

Short version: you cannot (and you probably should not want to).

Longer version: You've defined a shell function. You could actually even export that shell function into the environment `export -f cat`. But unless the Makefile was saying `bash -c cat ...` instead of just `cat` (or other reference to the same effect), it would not give you the behavior you wanted.

If you really insisted... and the Makefile did not use hard coded path (e.g. `/bin/cat`). You could write your own cat, place it somewhere and make this location precede other possible hits for `cat` (just put it up front).

There is also some chance (look in the make file) it uses a variable (e.g. `CAT`) to know what to call, so you could just provide your own definition if that was the case.

In any case though. I would discourage you from using workaround like these because the actual behavior of the machinery gets obfuscated by doing so. There is something declared here... and something else in the environment giving it a different meaning. Which is a very common source of mistakes and eventually non-obvious (harder to resolve) bugs.

---

Example/clarification to the function bit. I have a Makefile:

```
all:
    @echo foo
```

And define and export a function "overriding" echo. `echo() { /bin/echo "$@" bar; } ; export -f echo`. I run make and get:

```
$ make
foo
```

Because make just looks for `echo` in `PATH` (tries to `exec` and once it finds it, it runs it). If I changed it to have bash step in between, the exported function would kick in, but... that's an usual way to use commands in make and you'd have to edit the Makefile which you did not want:

```
all:
    @bash -c 'echo foo'
```

This would yield you the result you wanted:

```
$ make
foo bar
```

---

The other option I've mentioned. I've put behavior of that function into a script `/tmp/bin/echo` reading:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo "$@" bar
```

And I've modified the `PATH` env var `export PATH=/tmp/bin:$PATH`. Now even with the first form of the Makefile:

```
all:
    @echo foo
```

I get:

```
$ make
foo bar
```

But if the Makefile that is given says `/bin/echo` instead, I'd have no such luck. You could still change the binary... or change its behavior by forcing a shared library preload... but sounds quote extreme and fully exposes why this really might not be the best direction to take it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a shell function, because a shell function exists only in the local shell.  It's not passed to programs like `make`.  Also, GNU make always invokes `/bin/sh` by default, not `/bin/bash`, and your shell function above is written in bash syntax, so putting it in your `~/.bashrc` will have no impact.

You could run:

```
$ make SHELL=/bin/bash
```

and add that shell function to your `~/.bashrc` and that might work.

The only other thing you can do (assuming that your third party makefile invokes `cat` directly and doesn't use a variable like `$(CAT)` instead) is to create a `cat` shell script (not a function) and put it on your `PATH` before `/bin` and `/usr/bin` when you invoke make.  Something like:

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ vi tmp/cat
    ...add commands...
$ chmod 755 tmp/cat
$ PATH=$(pwd)/tmp:$PATH make ...
```

Of course when you do this you can't use `command cat ...` in your script, you'll have to use a fully-qualified path like `/bin/cat ...`